# How to create a capped resizable image prior to iOS5

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios5, insets

Does anyone know how to do this without using `[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]`? I'm trying to provide compatibility for users that cannot run iOS5.

```
UIEdgeInsets imgInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.f, 5.f, 13.f, 44.f);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"fileName"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:imgInsets]; // only available in iOS5+
```

Please note that I'm not looking to create a 1px stretchable image, I want to **tile** the area that is defined between the insets when the UIImage is resized. That is, `[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:]` does not do the trick.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this pre iOS 5 in the way you want unfortunately. The only option is `[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:]`. With it you have to specify a single pixel which gets tiled horizontally and vertically. Unfortunately there's no way to do what you want directly with UIImage pre iOS 5.

**UPDATED**: I've updated this answer because DTs was totally correct.

Comment: These 2 methods actually do very different things: the former will tile the area defined within the insets. That way you can have a pattern repeating. The latter will only repeat a single pixel or rows, in your example pixel 6,11. In effect, the image is stretched when resized, not tiled. It only works for images that have uniform colors, not patterns.

Comment: I posted a screenshot to explain better what the difference is: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/tilevsstretch.jpg/

Comment: Very good point DTs - I've updated accordingly. Not quite sure what I was thinking when I wrote that answer, apologies.